# What happens with Server tag

Tags: bug, tags

Currently I'm trying to add Server tag to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/746391/best-location-in-the-world-to-host-your-server/) question.
But when I add it, something strange happens. Here are the screenshots:

### Adding tags:

[image: Adding 2 tags here]

### Clicking "Save Edits" tells that "Server" tag does NOT exist:

[image: Clicking "Save Edits" tells that tag does NOT exist]

### And finally:

[image: One says it exists, another says it doesn't exist o_O]

### Question:

What's happening here? Am I missing smtg? Does the "Server" tag exist at all or we should add it?

Comment: server is blacklisted as it's a meta tag.

Comment: Oh it means I missed smtg. Then what tag can be [here](http://superuser.com/questions/746391/best-location-in-the-world-to-host-your-server) about "Server"?

Comment: that question's not a very good one & will be deleted soon. There's no need to retag that

Comment: OK, thanks for response.

Comment: retracting my comment about it being blacklisted - it's not, but not sure why it's not allowing you to create the tag - you have the necessary privileges

Comment: Hrm. There's a synonym that maps [servers] to [server], and the latter doesn't exist anymore since there are no questions in it. I'll see about reproducing this locally and figuring out what's happening and what behaviour makes the most sense, but in the meantime, I'd advise against using [server] as a tag since it carries very little useful information about any question it'd be on whatsoever. The *type* of a server would be important to know. Just "server" is meaningless.